# How to sort YAML using Jekyll Liquid

Tags: loops, sorting, github, yaml, jekyll

I have the following YML code that I am trying to sort `alphabetically` in Jekyll:

```
layout: project
title: Home renovation
link: http://urlgoeshere.com    
builtWith:
  - Concrete
  - Glass
  - Brick
  - Dirt
```

Here is my template code:

```
  <h4>Built With</h4>
    <ul class="list-unstyled list-inline list-responsibilities">
      {% for item in page.builtWith %}
        <li>{{ item }}</li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

What do I need to add to the `for` loop to get the `builtWith` items to sort `alphabetically`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
{% assign sorted = (page.builtWith | sort) %}
{% for item in sorted %}
```

Comment: Just a note that parentheses `(` `)` don't do anything in Liquid and you can remove them from this snippet.

Answer (score 0):

In the latest Jekyll version, using just `sort` tag doesn't work because you need to assign it to a variable first: `Liquid Warning: Liquid syntax error (line 24): Expected end_of_string but found pipe in "item in page.builtWith | sort"`.

If you are not using the latest version then it can work adding `sort` in the same line.

Using `assign` and `sort` tags is safer:

```
<h4>Built With</h4>
<ul class="list-unstyled list-inline list-responsibilities">
{% assign sorted = page.builtWith | sort %}
{% for item in sorted %}
<li>{{ item }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Outputs:

```
Built With

    Brick
    Concrete
    Dirt
    Glass
```